# How to access Id's of Fragment element (like: TextView, EditText etc ) in the MainActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, findviewbyid

Here is the Fragment.xml file. I created some elements (like TextView and ImageView). I assigned IDs to those elements.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivContact"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/contact" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Here is the Fragment.java file.

```
TextView tvName,tvTel;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
}
```

---

Here is the MainActivity.java file. I want to access the IDs of Fragment.xml file. In the MainActivity.java file. But I'm unable to access the IDs. It showing errer. I'm stuck. I had try so many time. But not solved. I  think this is old version to access the IDs. But I don't know how can I access the IDs in new version.

ERROR:@layout/activity_main does not contain a declaration with id tvName.

```
 TextView tvName,tvTel;
 EditText etName,etTel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvName = findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvTel = findViewById(R.id.tvTel);

    etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etTel = findViewById(R.id.etTel);
}
```

---

### Please help me, How can I access the IDs.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should never have to do that. If you want to communicate with the host activity you can use the `onAttach` method from the fragment or simply `requireActivity()`. Look at the example below

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        
        TextView tvName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvTel = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTel);

        TextView etName = view.findViewById(R.id.etName);
        TextView etTel = view.findViewById(R.id.etTel);

        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) requireActivity();
        

        tvName.setText(activity.sameFields);
        activity.someMethods();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if ((context instanceof MainActivity)) {
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;
            activity.someMethods();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **tvName.setText(activity.sameFields);
        activity.someMethods();** I am unable to do that

Comment: How can I communicate with MainActivity.java file.

Comment: What are you referring to when you talk about communicating with MainActivity?

Comment: You are unable to do what ?